# Android Studio webView "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" on a React js Project

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview

Im trying to show (https://may293.github.io/PWATest/) inside a webView component in android studio, but its not working.

the android SO in the device is android 5.1.1 build ID: LMY47V

The goal is to share information between the a PWa and a library .jar inside the android app.

always i got the same error message in logcat: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", source: https://may293.github.io/PWATest/static/js/main.27c55fe8.js (2)

the project is just a : npx create-react-app my-app
nothing was added to the files, i just upload to gitpages like the command execute.

the proyect works correctly in http//:localhost:3000 also in https://may293.github.io/PWATest/

this is my "WebViewActivity":

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private WebView webView;

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

            webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // Cargar la URL de tu aplicación web
            webView.loadUrl("https://may293.github.io/PWATest/");

        }
    }
```

i already tried to run it in a browswer in the android device and goes right.
just when im inside the android app its not working (not showing up).

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: webview version? Have you tried updating to the latest webview via the playstore?

Comment: i have this version in my build.gradle (app): ```` implementation("androidx.webkit:webkit:1.9.0")```` i already tested in a prior version (it didn't work).